# Google Maps V3 Icons Trimmed

Tags: google-maps, icons

I have a problem with Google Maps V3, in zoom 14 in one case some custom icons are cut off.

You can see it here: http://www.praguegayapartments.com if you zoom in it one step. Default is 13 because of this behavior. Would anyway have any suggestion regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue minutes ago, and found where my problem was.

Be sure that you place your markers' icon image with `integer` value, not with `string`.

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('icon.png',
    new google.maps.Size(parseInt(width), parseInt(height)),
    new google.maps.Point(parseInt(x), parseInt(y)),
    new google.maps.Point(parseInt(pointerX), parseInt(pointerY))  
);
```